# is redis command still atomic in redis cluster environment?

Tags: redis, command, atomic, redis-cluster

i know incr command is atomic in a or more redis server,but other command e.g. set command、Hset command that are still atomic in redis cluster environment

Answer (score 5):

For those commands supported by cluster mode, they are atomic. However, some commands are limited supported by cluster mode, e.g. commands that take multiple keys. For example, you can run `SADD` atomically in cluster mode, but you cannot run `SUNION`, unless all keys are mapped to the same hash slot. Also `hash tag` can help us map keys to the same slot.

Comment: You **can** run multi-key commands in the cluster, as long as the keys map to the same hash slot.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. And the hash tag can help us map keys to the same slot.

Comment: Then you'll remember next time ;)

Comment: is there any official notes or documentation related to this? I can't seem to find one

Comment: @M.R.Murazza You can check [this](https://redis.io/topics/introduction) and [this](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial).